# If string value in array then...vba

Tags: array, vba

Estoy trabajando con una macro y lo que quiero hacer es comparar los valores de una columna contra los valores en un arreglo y si lo encuentra eliminar la fila completa, lo que no se es la instrucción para buscar el valor, mi código:

```vb
Dim i, c, last_row As Integer
Dim myarray As Variant
Dim Product As String

myarray = Array("J8031A#ACC", "J8031A#ACQ", "A2W80A")
last_row = wsMissingSCM2.Range("A22").End(xlDown).Row

For c = 22 To last_row

 Product = wsMissingSCM2.Cells(c, 4).Value

 **If IsArray(Product) Then** 'Tengo este codigo pero no me funciona

    Rows(c).EntireRow.Delete

 End If
Next c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De [esta respuesta en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951687/how-to-search-for-string-in-an-array/10952705#10952705), lo que necesitas es una función auxiliar que verifique si un valor existe en un arreglo:

```vb
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

Y, ahora sí, usa la función para hacer lo que necesitas cuando encuentras el valor:

```vb
' ...
For c = 22 to last_row
    Product = wsMissingSCM2.Cells(c,4).value
    If IsInArray(Product, myarray) then
        Rows(c).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
next c
' ...
```